# Are there any other databases that use Map-Reduce for queries like CouchDB?

Tags: database, nosql, mapreduce, couchdb

After learning about CouchDB and Map-Reduce queries I've become very enthusiastic about them, but dislike Couch's revision and conflict model. Are there any other, 'lighter' NoSQL databases that also support using Map-Reduce to query data?

I don't mean in the sense that MongoDB does it. I mean one that does it efficiently as it's primary (or at least a first class) means of running a query.

The closest thing I've been able to find is [an abstraction layer on top of LevelDB](https://github.com/dominictarr/map-reduce).

Comment: map-reduce is cool huh? Is there anything in particular about CouchDB that is too heavy?

Comment: You've checked out Couchbase and don't care for it? When I think of a NoSQL solution that primarily focuses on map/reduce I think of Hadoop. I suppose I never think of the word 'light' when talking about map/reduce. =)

Comment: That main thing I'd like is in-place updates. Or even just not having to include the current _rev with every PUT. I know that can be done with update handlers, but that's even more inconvenient.